# jQuery mobile popup width varies by the content inside?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u8hay5q8/4/)

jquery mobile popup contains a `<ul>` in which each `<li>` is 33% wide.  The demo shows that the number of `<li>` affects the width of the popup (thus that of the `<li>`).  Wny?

How to have consistent `<li>` sizes regardless of the number of `<li>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to ensure consistent width is to give the UL element either a set width or a min-width:

```
.dot3-list {
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    min-width:240px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Also, as you are floating listitems within the UL, you need to apply the **[clearfix hack](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/)** so the UL will completely wrap the contained listitems:

```
/* Start of "Micro clearfix" */
.dot3-list { zoom: 1; }
.dot3-list:before,
.dot3-list:after { content: ""; display: table; }
.dot3-list:after { clear: both; }
/* End of "Micro clearfix" */
```

> Here is your updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/u8hay5q8/6/)**

### UPDATE:

It is better to set the width of the popup and allow the list to fill the width:

```
.ui-popup-container {
    width: 75%;
}
.dot3-list {
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/u8hay5q8/9/)**

Comment: Thanks for clearfix, but min-width only prevents the `<li>` being too small.  The width is still varying with the number of `<li>`.   A has more `<li>` in [this version](http://jsfiddle.net/u8hay5q8/8/), and `.dot3-list` in A is 324 vs 240 in B.

Comment: And I will need the popup be spanning the page width, so a fixed min-width or width is not the solution.  I guess this can be done without js.

Comment: @KaFaiLo, see this update to your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/u8hay5q8/9/ Instead of setting width of the UL, set width of the popup. Also you had data-corners="false" on one popup but not the other. If the popup gets taller than the screen causing a scrollbar to show, this can affect the width of the popup if you are using percentage...

Comment: [jsfiddle.net/ezanker/u8hay5q8/9](jsfiddle.net/ezanker/u8hay5q8/9)  is the answer.  Thank you @ezanker